# Pagination in Azure DataFactory with Certificate authentication

Tags: azure, pagination, azure-data-factory

I try to get data from an API that implements client side pagination. I have to authenticate with a certificate. The problem is I can't use the API LinkedService since this doesn't allow me to authenticate trough certificates so I am left with http linked service. Now with that service there is no pagination so I have to do it myself with controls. I have a variable that I iterate over but I can't figure out how to check if there were any results, in the last page I got, in order to know if it is time to stop.

In more details, I have a copy data activity followed by two set variables activities (since I cannot increment a variable in one) and an until activity. In order to get a page I send a skip and top variable in the copy activity, which tell where to start and how many entries to request, I increase the skip variable by the value of the top variable and with the until activity I repeat. How do I fill a variable with the amount of records I obtained so I get a stop condition in my until activity?

Is there another way to do it? I am playing with the thought of using a databricks activity just to do that but I feel like it is a bit exagereated since we don't use Databricks in this project so we would need a whole setup just to be able to do pagination.

Comment: Does your API tell you the total number of pages? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949173/how-can-i-consume-this-rest-api-in-azure-data-factory/56962908#56962908

Comment: @GregGalloway No it doesn't it sends back empty lists once I skip more than there are entries. But if there is a solution using that information I might be able to get it otherwise.