# Azure REST API - returning only 500 rows

Tags: azure-data-factory, rest

I am trying to use Rest API as data source in Azure Data Factory.

When I use the **Base URL** like bottom, it only imported 500 rows of data.

```
https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=[SELECT * FROM af6b8b82-3893-55d4-9cea-bf8101a05e05];
```

So, based on some of information that I got thru internet research, I tried adding few more parameters to raise the limit, but I did not have a luck.

```
https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=[SELECT * FROM af6b8b82-3893-55d4-9cea-bf8101a05e05][LIMIT 5000 OFFSET 5000];
```

Based on [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3950fa7b-98bc-4d3a-83ba-18fb76165c59/azure-application-insights-rest-api-returning-only-500-rows?forum=ApplicationInsights), it mentioned about adding these parameters ($top & $count=true).

I tried something like this, but, still it only imported 500 rows of data.

```
https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=[SELECT * FROM af6b8b82-3893-55d4-9cea-bf8101a05e05]&$top=10000&$count=true;
```

How do I incorporate in Azure Data Factory to go beyond 500 rows of data from Rest API?

This is the [web site](https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/dataset/4pq5-n9py) where it explains about this SQL query:

Since it mentioned about "Data Set" and "SQL Query", I am not sure which approach I should take.

Now, my question is, we are not strictly limiting output in JSON, correct?

I am curious, because, when I tried to download the data into JSON format, somehow, it appears that it is causing some error when I tried to read from JSON editor.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=[SELECT * FROM af6b8b82-3893-55d4-9cea-bf8101a05e05][LIMIT 500 OFFSET 500];` since from what I’m seeing in the docs that looks like how you should get page 2

Comment: @GregGalloway I just tried, and it inserted only 500 rows still.

Comment: yes, only 500 rows but it’s the second page of rows. you will have to loop through each page until you get less than 500 rows. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949173/how-can-i-consume-this-rest-api-in-azure-data-factory/56962908#56962908

Comment: @GregGalloway Thanks for the link. I updated my question (with the open question regards to approach beyond JSON format as an output). When I read the link you mentioned, it appears that output is in JSON format (OPENJSON(@json)). Referencing from the website of this data source (https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/dataset/4pq5-n9py), SQL query section did not specify that output should be in JSON.. I am just not finding where and how I should approach my issue. Should I use "Data Set" or should I stay with "SQL Query"?

Answer (score 0):

The REST API will only return a maximum of 500 results for any single request, you cannot change that.

You need to make successive requests increasing the offset parameter:

```
https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=[SELECT * FROM af6b8b82-3893-55d4-9cea-bf8101a05e05][LIMIT 500 OFFSET 0]; 

https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=[SELECT * FROM af6b8b82-3893-55d4-9cea-bf8101a05e05][LIMIT 500 OFFSET 500]; 

https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=[SELECT * FROM af6b8b82-3893-55d4-9cea-bf8101a05e05][LIMIT 500 OFFSET 1000]; 

https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=[SELECT * FROM af6b8b82-3893-55d4-9cea-bf8101a05e05][LIMIT 500 OFFSET 1500]; 

etc.
```

Example of how to retrieve all data in Powershell:

```
$offset = 0

do{
  $url = "https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/sql?query=[SELECT * FROM af6b8b82-3893-55d4-9cea-bf8101a05e05][LIMIT 500 OFFSET $offset];"
  write-progress "Getting data at offset $offset"
  $res = (invoke-webrequest $url).content | convertfrom-json
  $res | export-csv data.csv -append
  $offset += 500
}while ($res.count -eq 500)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It appears that I get about 15,000 of data. Do I manually change the OFFSET to 15000 this case?

Comment: Offset = 15000 will retrieve the last 316 records, the fact that fewer than 500 records are returned is your clue not to advance the offset to 15500. I doubt you'd do it manually, you'd advance the offset programatically in a loop.  I've added an example of that.

Comment: I guess putting each URLs like you have demonstrated is not the option, correct?  So we have to put one by one like that to make it work, correct? One URL would not work, right? After you gave me an example of Powershell option, I am trying to research into Azure Batch Linked Service option. Is this the right approach? It seems to be there are not many examples to follow in the internet. I would like to get some feedback regards to focusing on Azure Batch option. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, your Powershell script basically outputs into csv file, correct? Sorry. I am little bit confused. I am trying to use Rest API directly to pull data into Azure SQL database.

Comment: Listing each URL manually is not an option as if the volume of data changes the number of requests will change.

Comment: Yes the Powershell outputs to CSV, but that's not the important part. The key part is that it loops to increase the offset and detects when to stop, which was the crux of your question. If you now understand that concept you should mark this answer as accepted and ask a new question about Azure Batch Service.