# Azure Data Factory: Incrementing a number in the REST API request body

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

In [ADF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure#Data_management), I am currently working on a *copy data* function from a REST API URL. In the [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request body there are parameters like this:

```
{
    "anyStateChange": true,
    "timeInterval": {
        "field": "requestedOn",
        "operator": "lastndays",
        "value": "1"
    },
    "paginationStartIndex": 1,
    "numberOfRecords": 20
}
```

API Returns 3 Fields like this :

```
{
    "totalResults": X
    "startIndex" : Y
    "itemsPerPage" : Z
}
```

I am trying to determine the best way to increment the paginationStartIndex until it runs out of records in the loop.

I tried doing some adjustments to *pagination* rules, and other options which want to increment the page in the URL which doesn't work here.

Comment: can you share sample data?

Comment: Do you know how many records are present there?

Comment: If your REST API returns the total number of pages you can follow this pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56962908/5070440

Comment: The API does not return the total number of pages, only its current page index. It does return a total number of records. 

The number of records is variable because the API queries a dataset given a certain date range. Depending on the range and how far back the returned record set can be smaller or larger.

So, incrementing through the pages also would be necessary for the loop to stop once it hits an empty page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For incrementing a number in a REST API request body, you can use a *ForEach activity* as below.

In the *for each* activity settings, pass the value as a range of numbers you want to pass as below:

[image]

Then in the request body, pass the `@{item()}` for the parameter you want to increment sequentially.

[image]

This will also act as pagination.

Comment: Will this work if the range is dynamic? Or rather once it hits no records on range X will it stop trying to loop through pages? The API returns:

itemsPerPage
startIndex
totalNumberOfRecords

So the amount of pages is totalNumberOfRecords / itemsPerPage. Is there a way in the above range forEach, to make it something like :  @range(1, (totalNumberOfRecords/itemsPerPage) ?

Comment: Yes you can try this but before that you have to get the values of total no of records by using web activity. Then you can use the dynamic content to give dynamic range

Comment: Ok so pipeline steps  it would go like this:

Web Activity : Capture Total Records - > ForEach @range(1, TotalRecords/20), CopyData using the @{item()} ?

Comment: yes, this is how your pipeline will look.